# understanding mysql query performance using sean lahman mlb database

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently downloaded the [sean lahman](http://www.seanlahman.com/) sql and imported the data into a mysql db, and started playing around with some queries. My SQL knowledge is pretty slim; basic inner joins and simple subqueries, have never really gone beyond that. But this is a very cool dataset and right away I started having some performance issues I didn't really understand.

The following query returns the player id, some offensive stats, and the manager id of the top 5 Seattle Mariners HR hitters by joining the Batting and Managers tables:

```
select 
    b.playerID, b.yearID, b.H, b.HR, b.RBI, (b.H / b.AB) b_avg, mgr.managerID 
from 
    Batting b 
inner join 
    Managers mgr on b.yearID = mgr.yearID and b.teamID = mgr.teamID 
where   b.teamID = 'SEA' 
order by b.HR desc 
limit 5
    -> ;
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------------+
| playerID  | yearID | H    | HR   | RBI  | b_avg  | managerID  |
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------------+
| griffke02 |   1997 |  185 |   56 |  147 | 0.3043 | pinielo01m |
| griffke02 |   1998 |  180 |   56 |  146 | 0.2844 | pinielo01m |
| griffke02 |   1996 |  165 |   49 |  140 | 0.3028 | pinielo01m |
| griffke02 |   1999 |  173 |   48 |  134 | 0.2855 | pinielo01m |
| griffke02 |   1993 |  180 |   45 |  109 | 0.3093 | pinielo01m |
+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

That returned pretty quickly (0.11 secs). But when I tried to get the players and managers full names, the speed of the query decreased dramatically:

```
select 
    mp.nameLast plyr_first, mp.nameFirst plyr_last, b.yearID, b.H, b.HR, b.RBI, (b.H     / b.AB) b_avg, mm.nameLast mgr_last, mm.nameFirst mgr_lfirst 
from 
    Batting b 
inner join 
    Managers mgr 
on b.yearID = mgr.yearID and b.teamID = mgr.teamID 
inner join 
    Master mp 
    on b.playerID = mp.playerID 
inner join 
    Master mm on mgr.managerID = mm.managerID 
where 
    b.teamID = 'SEA' 
order by 
    b.HR desc limit 5;
+------------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+------------    +
| plyr_first | plyr_last | yearID | H    | HR   | RBI  | b_avg  | mgr_last | mgr_lfirst |
+------------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+------------    +
| Griffey    | Ken       |   1997 |  185 |   56 |  147 | 0.3043 | Piniella | Lou        |
| Griffey    | Ken       |   1998 |  180 |   56 |  146 | 0.2844 | Piniella | Lou            |
| Griffey    | Ken       |   1996 |  165 |   49 |  140 | 0.3028 | Piniella | Lou        |
| Griffey    | Ken       |   1999 |  173 |   48 |  134 | 0.2855 | Piniella | Lou        |
| Griffey    | Ken       |   1993 |  180 |   45 |  109 | 0.3093 | Piniella | Lou        |
+------------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+------------    +
5 rows in set (11.43 sec)
```

here are the relevant rows on the master table (lots are excluded, but these are the main ones)

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| lahmanID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| playerID     | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| managerID    | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nameFirst    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nameLast     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I basically started with the Batting table as that is where the data is. I then added on the Managers table and still got pretty good results. I then joined the Master table and got the players first and last name, and that wasn't bad, but it's the second join of the Master table that is giving me the problem.

When I modified the query to only return the manager id, and not the first and last name of the manager, it was much faster, about a quarter second. Any ideas as to how get the first/last names of both player and manager with good performance, and can you point me in the right direction of how the query is being slowed down?

thanks,
bp

Comment: How are the rows of managers vs. players broken out on the MASTER table? Can you please give a list of columns on the MASTER table?

Comment: Done. A full list of the database table is available here: [link](http://seanlahman.com/files/database/readme2012.txt)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be correct but can you just try changing the join for the manager's names to this:

```
inner join Master mm
  on mgr.managerID = mm.playerID
```

So you'd run:

```
select mp.nameLast plyr_first,
       mp.nameFirst plyr_last,
       b.yearID,
       b.H,
       b.HR,
       b.RBI,
       (b.H / b.AB) b_avg,
       mm.nameLast mgr_last,
       mm.nameFirst mgr_lfirst
  from Batting b
 inner join Managers mgr
    on b.yearID = mgr.yearID
   and b.teamID = mgr.teamID
 inner join Master mp
    on b.playerID = mp.playerID
 inner join Master mm
    on mgr.managerID = mm.playerID
 where b.teamID = 'SEA'
 order by b.HR desc limit 5;
```

I just want to rule out a bad join as the cause. If it doesn't work, can you take the "limit 5" out of the query and see if any rows are duplicates and/or otherwise "bad"?

Comment: hi, thanks for the repsonse. That query returned an empty set in 12.03 secs. The manager and player id's are not the same in the master table.